# How to save each string in a text file C++

Tags: c++, string

I have a txt file, named `mytext.txt`, from which I want to read and save every line in `C++`. When  I run the binary, I do `./file <mytext.txt`

I'd like to do something

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(std::cin,line)){
//here I want to save each line I scan}
```

but I have no clue on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `std::vector<string>` to save the lines as so:

```
///your includes here
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::string line;
while(std::getline(std::cin,line))
    lines.push_back(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the following documentation and example:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Edit upon recommendation:

In the provided link below they explain how to open and close a text file, read lines and write lines and several other functionalities. For completeness of this answer an example will be given below:

```
// writing on a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    myfile << "This is a line.\n";
    myfile << "This is another line.\n";
    myfile.close();
  }
  else cout << "Unable to open file";
  return 0;
}
```

The above script will write the 2 lines into the text file named example.txt.

You can then read these lines with a somewhat similar script:

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      cout << line << '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Best regards

Ruud

Comment: posting only a link as answer is as good as saying "you can google it". Adding links is fine, but then at least summarize